# Is there a way to push the results of a PostgreSQL query into a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, loops, backend, psql

Just looking to see if there's an elegant solution to this problem:

Is there a way to loop through the results of a psql query and return a specific result based on the SQL query?

For example, let's say I wanted to `SELECT amount_available FROM lenders ORDER BY interest_rate`, and I wanted to loop through the column looking for any available amounts, add those available amounts to a variable, and then once that amount reached a certain figure, exit.

More verbose example:

Let's say I have someone who wants to borrow $400. I want to go through my lenders table, and look for any lender that has available funds to lend. Additionally, I want to start looking at lenders that are offering the lowest interest rate. How could I query the database and find the results that satisfy the $400 loan at the lowest interest rate, and stop once I've reached my goal, instead of searching the whole db? And can I do that inside a JavaScript function, returning those records that meet that criteria?

Maybe I'm trying to do something that's not possible, but just curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You translate your requirement into the SQL language. After all, SQL is a descriptive language. The database engine then figures out how to process the request.

Your example sound like

```
SELECT name
FROM lenders
WHERE property >= 400
ORDER BY interest_rate
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```